# jsp errors IsUserInRole() and others

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsp, servlets

I am trying to redeploy a project that fell into my hands. It's a maven project with javax.servlet-api among the dependencies it's using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
        <version>2.5</version>  
    </dependency>
```

To this, I'm getting error in jsp-s, including the following.

> The method getIsUserInRole() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest.

and

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - Undefined attribute name 
>        (id).
>       - Unknown tag (canvas).
>       - Undefined attribute name 
>        (style).

For this, I changed the servlet version to 3.0.1:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
        <version>3.0.1</version>  
    </dependency>
```

However, i still have the same errors. The jstl version (ir relevant) on build path is 1.2.

How to fix this?

Why am i to explicitly define servlet-api of any kind, doesn't the servlet container have it? 
If so, how to tell JBoss to use servlet version 3.0.1?

I'm running JBoss 7.1 on Eclipse Neon. I tried and got the same thing on Eclipse Mars.

TIA.

//-------------------------------

EDIT:

getIsUserInRole() is the name coming up in Eclipse problem report. here's a snapshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06GOj.png)

The method name is spelled correctly in the code:

```
<c:if test="${not empty pageContext.request.userPrincipal}">
    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.isUserInRole('ROLE_ADMIN')}">
                <button class="custombutton" id="admin" style="font-size: 150%; height:80px; width: 100%">Administration [Admin. Profile]</button>

    </c:if>
</c:if>
```

Also, Eclipse is reporting warnings for all canvas items-- tags, attributes names, etc. isn't recognizing them:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqEfD.png)

//-----------------

EDIT2:

There is Spring 3.2.8 in this project. could it intercept the servlet definition in some way? However, the pom.xml dependency hierarchy shows no indication of it.

Also, I haven't changed any Spring dependencies in the project, they are the same as the one that's been deployed and running now.

This looks like a build problem, however I can't see it. The previous version was deployed on IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

No wonder it produces compile errors: The method is wrongly-spelled: It is `isUserInRole`, and not `getIsUserInRole`. The consequence is that, within a tag, **you must always omit the verb**:

```
${pageContext.request.userInRole('ROLE_ADMIN')}
```

> Why am i to explicitly define servlet-api of any kind, doesn't the servlet container have it? If so, how to tell JBoss to use servlet version 3.0.1?

In compilation, the web container is not already available, so you actually **need** to put on the classpath a JEE runtime (the `servlet-api.jar`). You have done it well.

> If so, how to tell JBoss to use servlet version 3.0.1?

AFAIK no way: You choose which servlet container (and version) you want to use, and it comes bundled with a specific runtime. So you must accomplish to that runtime when compiling.

The warning about the `canvas` tag: Ensure you are coding in **HTML5**: Put this declaration at the beginning of the JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" 
    import="..."
%><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    ...
</html>
```

Comment: the name of the method is right in jsp. "get" is what Eclipse is prepending to it in both problems and markers windows. please see the edit updating the Q on this.

Comment: that didn't help either. I merely imported javax.servlet.*